# Show that a line is a linear subvariety of dimension $1$, and that a linear subvariety of dimension $1$ is the line through any two of its points.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $P = (a_1,\ldots,a_n), Q = (b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ be distinct points of $\Bbb A^n$.

The line through
$P$ and $Q$ is defined to be $\{a_1+t(b_1−a_1),\ldots,a_n+t(b_n−a_n)) \mid t \in k\}$.

(b) Show that a line is a linear subvariety of dimension
$1$, and that a linear subvariety of dimension $1$ is the line through any two of its points.

(d) Let $P, P' \in \Bbb A^2$, $L_1,L_2$ two distinct lines through $P, L'_1, L'_2$
distinct lines through $P'$. Show that there is an
affine change of coordinates $T$ of  $\Bbb A^2$ such that $T (P) = P'$
and $T (L_i) = L'_i$, $i = 1, 2$.

Clearly constructing map $f:L \to k$ s.t $(a_1+t(b_1−a_1),\ldots,a_n+t(b_n−a_n)) \to t$ gives isomorphism $L$ and $k$ so it is of dimension $1$ but conversely how to do?

For definition of dimension please see http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf page 20 Problem 2.14.

Answer (score 1):

For (b), let $L$ be the given line. The affine change of coordinates $T_1=(X_1-a_1, \ldots,X_n-a_n )$ will take $L$ to $L'=\{(t(b_1−a_1),\ldots,t(b_n−a_n)) \mid t \in k\}$.

Now, for at least one $j$, $a_j\neq b_j$ ($P$ and $Q$ distinct). This means that $L'=V(P_1(X_1, \ldots,X_n ),\ldots,P_{j-1}(X_1, \ldots,X_n ),P_{j+1}(X_1, \ldots,X_n )\ldots, P_n(X_1, \ldots,X_n ))$

where $P_k= (b_k - a_k)^{-1}X_k-(b_j - a_j)^{-1}X_j$ if $b_k-a_k \neq 0$ and $P_k=X_k$ otherwise. Indeed, if $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in V(P_1,\ldots,P_{j-1},P_{j+1}\ldots, P_n)$, set $t=(b_j - a_j)^{-1}x_j$ and then $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)= (t(b_1−a_1),\ldots,t(b_n−a_n)) $. The inverse inclusion is trivial. Now $T_2=(P_1,\ldots,P_{j-1},X_j,P_{j+1},\ldots, P_n)$ is an affine change of coordinates that takes $L'$ to $V(X_1,\ldots,X_{j-1},X_{j+1},\ldots,X_{n})$. If necessary, add a permutation of the indices (this also is an affine change of coordinates) to give you $V(X_2,\ldots,X_{n})$ and you are done, since the composition of affine changes of coordinates is an affine change of coordinates.

On the other hand, suppose $V$ is a linear subvariety of dimension 1. Then $V^T=V(X_2,\ldots, X_n)$ for an affine change of coordinates $T$, so $V=V(X_2,\ldots, X_n)^{T^{-1}}$, with $T^{-1}$ also an affine change of coordinates, say $(a^1_1 X_1+ \ldots +a^n_1 X_n + a^0_1,\ldots, a^1_n X_1+ \ldots +a^n_n X_n + a^0_n)$. If $(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \in V$ then $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=(a^1_1 X_1+ \ldots +a^n_1 X_n + a^0_1,\ldots, a^1_n X_1+ \ldots +a^n_n X_n + a^0_n)(t,0,\ldots,0)$ hence $$(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=(a^1_1 t + a^0_1,\ldots, a^1_n t+ \ldots + a^0_n)$$ Now, with $t_0 \neq t_1$ set $t=t_0 + s(t_1 - t_0)$ to see that this is the line through the distinct points corresponding with $t_0$ and $t_1$ respectively.

As for (d), this was answered here [Affine change of coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159953/affine-change-of-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

See what I have got

b) if $A$ is a one dimensional subvariety & $V=V(F_1, \cdots , F_r)$ where $F_i$'s are polynomial of degree $1$; i.e

$F_i= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}X_j$ & we know $V^T=V(F_1(T), \cdots , F_r(T))=V(X_2, \cdots , X_n)$ I think this implies putting $X_1=c\in k$ and $F_i=X_i+ c(b_i-a_i)$

d) Here for $T(P)=P'$ we have to use translation matrix and $T(L)=L'$ we have to use rotation..